# Google Maps API v2 - How Do I Programmatically Set The GoogleMapOptions?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a GoogleMapOptions object with a bunch of stuff set but I do not know how to actually apply these options object for my map.

I am using the support map fragment and after looking at the docs I see only one method which is the new instance which takes a GoogleMapOptions object but with my implementation I cannot call this.

here is some code which I shortened to not clutter this question.

```
public class Map extends SupportMapFragment
{

    private OnMapReadyCallback callback;

    public static SupportMapFragment newInstance(OnMapReadyCallback callback)
    {

        Map map = new Map();
        map.callback = callback;
        return map;
    }
```

This class extends the SupportMapFragment and I define my own newInstance implementation which takes a OnMapReadyCallback variable. This is held in the field callback and passed to the method getMapAsync(callback)

And then in the main Activity which implements the OnMapReadyCallback, the Google map object is initialised.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{

this.googleMap = googleMap;
}
}
```

So how would I apply the options object? Specifically I want to set the initial map position without it starting from the world perspective and zooming where it needs to (its a bit costly!).

Thank you for reading. Please let me know if there is any omissions that I can fill in.

Please note: I cannot use the XML implementation because in my app, the Google map only appears if its explicitly requested by the user. I do not want to use the visibility approach as this would waste memory

Answer (score 1):

> Please note: I cannot use the XML implementation because in my app, the Google map only appears if its explicitly requested by the user.

You seem to be solving wrong problem here. If the above is your reason, then you should simply keep empty container in your layout and when user request your map, instantiate map fragment and add to your layout. And your map fragment (subclass most likely) can use XML layout so then.

Answer (score 1):

Its so **simple** but GoogleMapOptions can be passed just to MapFragments/MapView which added **programmically** (Not in a Layout file/XML):

1- create your desired option collection.

2- pass it via '**newInstance**' .

like this:

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true)
                .mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                  SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options );
```

In this case i'm using **dynamic** MapFragment.

---

**But** if you defined your Fragment in **Layout** file so just control it by options provided in 'onMapReady' callback function:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE); 
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

I hope it'ld be useful for some one.

Answer (score 0):

I would override the `static SupportMapFragment newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options)` method of the `SupportMapFragment`. Then you can pass your `GoogleMapOptions` object in as a parameter when you call the `static SupportMapFragment newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options)` method

You can get a `GoogleMap` object from this `SupportMapFragment` object by doing this:

```
GoogleMap map = super.newInstance(options).getMap;
```